# Using Union and Contains in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL Query that uses both a Union and "IN" Statement

```
select FirstName 
From Person
where Lastname in ('Smith','Jones')
and MiddleInitial In ('A','G','M',)

UNION

Select PersonFirstName as Firstname
FROM BusinessPerson
WHERE CorporateName in ('Jones','Thomas')
And CorporateDirection IN ('N','S')
```

I have a custom Object that includes PersonFirstName, LastName, MiddleInitial, corporateName and corporatedirection as properties.

I was trying to load the union unfiltered into memory once and then write linq queries off the collection rather than go to the database for every request.

Since I want to filter on properties of each object in the collection, I was trying to use the contains off each property  but was not having much success.

I have a string array of Letters, and a string array of Names for some of my filters but failed to apply them corretly to a Linq query, and wasnt sure how I could get a contains to work with properties on the objects within the collection.

I was trying something like

```
string[] corporateNameCollection = new string[] { "Kmart", "Walmart" };

var filteredObject =  personCollection.Where(b=>b.CorporateName.Contains(corporateNameCollection ));
```

Any suggestions on using the string array against properties on the collection object ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
.Where(b => corporateNameCollection.Contains(b.CorporateName));
```

This is then saying does the `corporateNameCollection` contain each of the `b.CorporateName`.
And should be translated to an `IN` in Linq-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if the string array contains an element matching `CorporateName`, like this:

```
string[] corporateNameCollection = new string[] { "Kmart", "Walmart" };
var filteredObject = personCollection
    .Where(b => corporateNameCollection.Contains(b.CorporateName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] corporateNameCollection = new string[] { "Kmart", "Walmart" };

     var filteredObject =  personCollection.Where(b=>corporateNameCollection.Contains(  b.CorporateName));
```

This should work.